# Набор правил по которым строка может пройти валидацию

Tags: delphi, строки

И снова я со своим форматом TUTDF. Вопрос заключается в следующем, есть строка: 
Вася пошёл в магазин "Огонёк 23" и купил там #12 яблок. 
Задача заключается в создании набора символов по которым строка может пройти валидацию например:

```
['А'..'Я', 'а'..'я', 'a'..'z', 'A'..'Z', '.', ' ', ',', ''', '-',]
```

Т.е. в этой строке, могу находиться данные символы/наборы но больше ничего там не должно быть. Опробовал множество функций как например:

```
N := 'qwerty';
B := LastDelimiter(N, parse);
```

Но она лишь ищет крайнее вхождение набора в строку... т.е. для моей задачи, выходит так, что я должен перечислить в ней все возможные символы которым нельзя находиться в строке, что весьма затруднительно. Скажите, есть ли обратная ей возможность, наподобие in[набор] но для случая поиска символов из набора в строке типа string?

Comment: как на счет пройтись циклом по строке, и проверять каждый символ на вхождение во множество (in[набор])?    Или я не правильно понял вопрос?

Comment: Да, такой вариант идеален для данного случая, но не для моего, ведь нюанс заключается в том, что мне необходимо обработать 700000 + символов... а это весьма долго.

Comment: на сколько я знаю, в Delphi не предусмотрена какая-то реализация операции разности множеств, которую фактически надо выполнить. По этому проверка на вхождение в цикле скорее всего самый быстрый вариант...    
Кстати, 700 000 символов - это не так и долго...

Comment: Да... видимо Вы правы. Спасибо. А можно ли как-нибудь читать строку посимвольно и узнавать что это за символ, буква, цифра, или и т.д.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читать что такое регулярные выражения. и использовать **RegExp** вам как ключ к гуглю

Comment: Даа... видимо вариантов лучше проверки в цикле и регулярных выражений лучше нет. Думал есть одна такая, волшебная функция, которая могла бы помочь. Большое спасибо Вам за ответ. Буду пробовать вычислить скорость между этими 2-мя подходами и найти для себя оптимальный.

Comment: так это и есть волшебная функция.
другой вопрос на сколько просто понять как регулярку писать.

Comment: Как её писать я знаю ещё с PHP, просто в нём же, были интересные функции для подобных действий. Жаль, что их нет в DELPHI

Answer (score 0):

Может так

```
if pos('xxx',Str)>0 then ...
```

И так по всем возможным вариантам вхождения (если их небольшое количество).

Или так (в цикле посимвольно)

```
if (ord(Str[i])>=48)and(ord(Str[i])<=57)then ...
```

проверка одни ли в строке цифры.

Когда речь идет о больших объемах данных, я всегда использую базу данных (люблю MySQL).
Там делаю так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.point FROM table1 WHERE (table1.date1 LIKE "%%") AND (table1.date1 LIKE "%xyz%") ORDER BY table1.date1
```

для создания запросов использую MySQLQwery, выполняются запросы очень быстро (миллисекунды). Попробуйте.

Comment: на файлах со строками 100 000 и более символов , это будет очень долго.